# How to make style property names to lowercase

Tags: javascript, html, object, javascript-objects, value-of-css-property

so i have a object list for styles like this,

```
 const styles = {
            'font': 'font',
            'fontSize': 'font-size',
            'fontFamily': 'font-family',
            'fontVariant': 'font-variant',
            'fontWeight': 'font-weight',
            'fontStyle': 'font-style',
            'margin': 'margin',
        };
```

```
<div style='MARGIN:10px; FLOAT:left'></div>
```

`FYI`-i'm using an editor so that when i paste the HTML code, sometimes it has those property names in `UPPERCASE` .

how to do i make sure that all the property names are `lowercase` what function/method should i use to check the case?

Comment: what Editor are you using?

Comment: @TheFool CKEditor 5

Comment: you want to disable the setting or do some javascript operation?

Comment: well there is no setting for it given by them for it, so what i'm trying is that if some website has HTML with styles but the property name is uppercase so i want them to apply it in the editor but the editor thinks its something else so i want is `MARGIN` -> `margin`.

Comment: @SDP so based on your latest comment, you wanted to convert `MARGIN` to `margin`? i thought you wanted to check if its lowercase of uppercase

Comment: so the website you copy it from has the styles like that? The editor just pastes them as you copy them?

Comment: @TheFool yes

@Anonymouse yes i want to know how can i convert/change those property names because `lowercase` names are getting through but the `UPPERCASE` one's are not showing and no styles are applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to combine what has been said already.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(p => {
  p.setAttribute('style', p.getAttribute('style').toLowerCase())
  console.log(p)
})
```

```html
<p style="COLOR: red;">Foo</p>
<p style="COLOR: blue;">Bar</p>
<p style="COLOR: green;">Baz</p>
```

That said, I wouldn't do it at runtime. Maybe do it once and serve the transformed HTML directly to the user. Maybe even some automated setup with gulp or 11ty.

The style are also visible without transforming. (for me in chrome)

Answer (score 1):

If you can use ES6, then you could create a new object using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
const lowerCaseStyles = Object.entries(styles).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key.toLowerCase()]: value}));
```

Comment: i dont think this is what he wanted, but i'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

If im not wrong, you wanted to check if the properties of the style attribute are UPPERCASED or lowercased

First of all, you can first get the value of the style attibute like

```
const value = document.querySelector("div").getAttribute("style");
//this will return 'MARGIN:10px; FLOAT:left'
```

then you can simply turn them to lowercase with `toLowerCase`

```
const lowercased = value.toLowerCase();
```

and then you can check if the properties with something like

```
return value === lowercased
```

```html
<div style='margin:10px; float:left'></div> returns true
<div style='MARGIN:10px; FLOAT:left'></div> returns false
```